# Stop scroll on inner div using css

Tags: css

I have my html as below

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="tabs" class="pages">
  </div>
  <div id="rows">
</div>
```

css

```
 .pages {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
 }
```

How can I stop tabs div from scrolling when the user scrolls the main div?

Comment: you can use `overflow:hidden`. to avoid scrolling

Comment: you could use [position sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) on the tabs

Comment: What do you mean by "stop tabs div from scrolling"? Stick the tabs div to the top of the page even after scrolling? Have a scroll for the rest of your document excluding tabs div?

Comment: Sorry just realised that the solution does not work. If the browser is restored, the div disappears